# Join by specific length of character

Tags: python

I want to join items in a list of lists based on these conditions:

- Item 1 is exactly 6 characters of length, and
- Item 2 is exactly 4 characters of length.

Input

```
list_of_lists = [
    ['912000', '0068', '6050457605142768217'],
    ['67','956532', '7201', '2549'],
    ['956811', '8334', '1748'],
    ['956718', '3693', '1551861252553'],
    ['956723', '0486', '86373']
]
```

Desired output:

```
list_of_lists = [['9120000068'], ['9565327201'], ['9568118334'], ['9567183693'], ['9567230486']]
```

Comment: How have you attempted to solve this?

Comment: What is your question about this homework assignment you have? Have you tried solving it yourself? If so, show us your code and describe what is going wrong. I'd also note that the problem statement seems under-specified. Do the two elements you're going to join need to be adjacent, or can there be elements in between them? Or could they even be out of order? The example input isn't very helpful because it only illustrates two different situations, where the desired values are at the start, or where one element (of an invalid size) precedes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just concatenate in a list comprehension, and use the `len` of the desired elements to filter out as you do so

```
>>> [[i+j] for i, j, *_ in list_of_lists if len(i)==6 and len(j)==4]
[['9120000068'], ['9568118334'], ['9567183693'], ['9567230486']]
```

Comment: Doesn't this output miss the second element in the test case OP provided?

Comment: According to the conditions they listed in their requirements, the second element is invalid and should not be in their output list.